# How to pick the right character encoding for exports?

Tags: data-export

The "[Weekly Export Service](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_exportdata.htm&language=en)" has a dropdown titled "Export File Encoding" with the following options:

- ISO-8859-1 (General US & Western European, ISO-LATIN-1)
- Unicode
- Unicode (UTF-8)
- Japanese (Windows)
- Japanese (Shift-JIS)
- Chinese National Standard (GB18030)
- Chinese Simplified (GB2312)
- Chinese Traditional (Big5)
- Korean
- Unicode (UTF-16, Big Endian)
- Big5 Traditional Chinese (HKSCS)
- Japanese (Shift_JIS-2004)

Quick analysis shows that the options appear to breakdown into the following groups:

- Chinese-based
- Japanese-based
- Korean-based
- Unicode-based

According to one source, "if you live in the United States or Western Europe, you don't have to change the Export File Encoding selection" from the default encoding, which appears to be ISO-8859-1.

How do you decide what is correct option? Are there any tradeoffs in selecting one format of another if you're not 100% sure what encoding the data is in, or might be used in outside of Saleforce?

---

Putting aside the data encoding "really used" in the data set, appears that as of 2012, [UTF-8 was the most popular according to Google](http://googleblog.blogspot.ca/2012/02/unicode-over-60-percent-of-web.html):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an 8 bit character set such as [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) means that any characters stored in Salesforce that can't be represented by one of those 256 numbers will be missing from your export and so lost.

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) avoids this risk. It uses a single byte for the ASCII characters and then more bytes to encode other characters. So practically speaking it is a "lossless" encoding that doesn't consume needless space for the common case of English language text. If you are not 100% sure what characters you have in your org UTF-8 is the way to go.

A downside of UTF-8 is that any tool used to view or process the data must have UTF-8 support built in.

I assume Salesforce provide many choices as a convenience, so that if the export is destined for a system that uses a specific encoding you can get to that encoding in one step.